Solution operator to an ODE
Let us put the discussion formally. I am reading a paper about the following ODE:
$$
\partial_t P(t) + H_t P(t) = 0, \ P(t = T) = x
$$
where $H_t$ is some operator,
Then the author claims that the solution is given by $P(t) = U_{tT} x$, and $U_{st}$ is defined by:
$$
U_{st} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\Delta_{st} H_{t_0})(1+\Delta_{st} H_{t_1}) \cdots (1+\Delta_{st} H_{t_n}),
$$
where $\Delta_{st} = \frac{t - s}{n}$ and $t_i = s + i\Delta_{st}$.
My question is about the expression of $U_{st}$. How do we get the infinite product expression? I think the solution operator will look like
$$
U_{st} = e^{\int_s^t H(\tau) d\tau}.
$$
Could anyone give me some hints? I think we don't need many details on the underlying spaces or the operator, feel free to put any nice assumption if needed.

Out of curiousity, what is the context for this paper? It's reminiscent of the Schrodinger equation and the corresponding time-evolution operator.

@Semiclassical It is "The Smile in Stochastic Volatility Models" by Bergomi and Guyon; they mention in the paper that their technique comes from quantum mechanism.

Thanks. You may want to google on the basis of "semigroup methods in differential equations", e.g., the notes here.

Te exponential integral is only then the correct solution when all the operators $H_t$ commute.

@Semiclassical Hi thank you for the reference. I am not sure if I misinterpret the result: it looks like that the reference you gave concerns only the equations like $u_t = Au$, where $A$ is NOT time dependent; but I think I should look at the theory regarding $u_t = B(t) u(t)$. Did I miss something?

That's correct, I had missed that that particular source was more limited.
